# hyperref Choicemenu adapting space between multiple buttons

Tags: hyperref, forms

I am trying to create a fillable form with the hyperref package. The problem is that I want to extend the space between the radio buttons inside all of the \ChoiceMenu s which are aligned on top of each other. Because then I can fit the categories above them. What are your suggestions ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, landscape, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\def\DefaultWidthofChoiceMenu{9cm}%
\def\DefaultHeightofChoiceMenu{0.8\baselineskip}
\def\DefaultWidthofChoiceMenu{0.8\baselineskip}
\def\DefaultHeightofText{1.2\baselineskip}
                                             Never   Rarely   Once in a While  Fairly Often Always\\                                                        
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{10cm}p{10cm}@{}}                                                                 
\rule{0pt}{4ex}1.) helps me when I need it. &\ChoiceMenu[name=optionB,radio,radiosymbol=, align = 2]{}{,,,,,,,} \\
\rule{0pt}{4ex}
2.) would make me feel comfortable in a new situation.&\ChoiceMenu[name=optionA,radio,radiosymbol=, align = 2]{}{,,,,,,,}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `{,,,,,}` for the choice buttons it is better to insert  some "blank" choice labels that occupy some space; below I have used `\qquad`.

I don't know how compatible this is with your use-case, but as far as possible I would automate this. For example, using the [array](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package you can define a new column type and have this (semi-)automatically insert the question number and the choice menu. I say semi-automatically, because you still need to put `&\`` at the end of each row to insert the choice buttons.

Finally, I have defined a macro `\Choicemenu` that inserts the choice menu, with the `name` set to `optionA`, `optionB`, ... based on the question number. The advantage of doing this is that if you need to make changes to the radio buttons then you only have to do it in one place.

With this in place, the output that you get is:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, landscape, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcounter{question}% a counter for the questions
\renewcommand\thequestion{\arabic{question}).\space}

% Define new column type that inserts the question number and the
% choice menu. It increments the question counter, inserts the 
% question number and then puts the choice menu at the end
\newcolumntype{Q}{>{\refstepcounter{question}\thequestion}p{120mm}r<{\Choicemenu}}

% Define a macro to insert the choice menu so that we only have to
% make changes to it in one place. The name is automatically set to
% optionA, optionB, ... based on the question number
\newcommand\Choicemenu{%
  \ChoiceMenu[name=option\Alph{question},
              radio,radiosymbol=,
              align=2,
              height=1mm,
              width=4mm]{}{\qquad,\qquad,\qquad,\qquad,\qquad}
}%

\def\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{document}
% Not sure that these are necessary?
%\def\DefaultHeightofChoiceMenu{0.8\baselineskip}
%\def\DefaultWidthofChoiceMenu{0.8\baselineskip}
%\def\DefaultHeightofText{.92\baselineskip}
\begin{Form}
  \begin{tabularx}\textwidth{@{}Q@{}}
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{Never Rarely Sometimes Often Always}\\
    Helps me when I need it&\\
    Would make me feel comfortable in a new situation&\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Note the `\multicoumn` is necessary for the first row of the `tabular` environment to override the `Q` column type.

Comment: Andrew, Thanks a lot that was super helpful! Also for all the descriptions! Never really worked much with macros in latex. This solution would have never come to my mind! Best, Ben